# Compile linux kernel deb-pkg target without generating dbg package?

Tags: linux, debian

I am building linux kernels the debian way as instructed (for the most part) by the [Debian Linux Kernel Handbook](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-common-tasks.html#s-kernel-org-package). So for the compilation step I use target `deb-pkg`, and on successful termination of `make deb-pkg` there are a few debian packages generated in the parent directory:

```
linux-firmware-image-VERSIONS.deb
linux-headers-VERSIONS.deb
linux-image-VERSIONS.deb
linux-image-VERSION-dbg_VERSION.deb
linux-libc-dev_VERSIONS.deb
```

Often times I find myself only installing `linux-image-x.y.z.deb` with the other four packages remaining unused. This wouldn't be much of a problem, but I keep finding that generating the package containing the kernel debugging symbols (`linux-image-x.y.z-dbg_x.y.z_arch.deb`) takes a significant amount of time. I'm wondering if there is a way to indicate to the `deb-pkg` build target not to generate debugging symbol packages?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer given by MariusMatutiae wasn't quite the one I was expecting, but I did take a look at some of the kernel build scripts and have found a workable solution. The script that generates the resulting debian packages is [`scripts/package/builddeb`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/package/builddeb). Looking at this script, the portions that build the package with debugging symbols are surrounded by conditionals dependent on `BUILD_DEBUG` which greps the given `KCONFIG` for `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`.

So to stop generating debian packages with debugging symbols, currently you need to disable the kernel `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` option:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=n
```

Comment: I did this and I started getting random errors relating to netlink messages being unnecessarily large and redundant data being in them. YMMV

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I didn't want to actually disable debugging information but the dbg package takes forever to build and I wasn't going to install it. I edited `scripts/package/builddeb` and at the very end of the file is where it checks for DEBUG_INFO and builds the dbg package. I just commented out that whole block. So I still have debugging but the package build goes a whole lot faster.

Answer (score 6):

[kernel-handbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20180204081635/https://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-common-tasks.html#s-common-building) suggests this:

> The build will use less disk space if the CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO option is disabled. Debuginfo is only needed if you plan to use binary object tools like crash, kgdb, and SystemTap on the kernel.

This can be achieved by this command:

```
cd linux-source-4.12
scripts/config --disable DEBUG_INFO
```

Comment: Can you give a summary of what the handbook says regarding why this command should be used, and exactly what it does?  We’d rather have information like that here, on our site, in case the link goes down.

Comment: the command sets `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=n` - the Debian handbook now lives at https://debian-handbook.info/get/ & more specifically at https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.kernel-compilation.html

Comment: This answer doesn't have the intended effect on kernel 5.19 - dbg file is produced.

Comment: @Marcus how did you solve it for 5.19+ ?

Comment: @DanglingPointer added an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

For those compiling a modern kernel version (5.19+), these are the config symbols to change:

```
scripts/config --undefine GDB_SCRIPTS
scripts/config --undefine DEBUG_INFO
scripts/config --undefine DEBUG_INFO_SPLIT
scripts/config --undefine DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED
scripts/config --undefine DEBUG_INFO_COMPRESSED
scripts/config --set-val  DEBUG_INFO_NONE       y
scripts/config --set-val  DEBUG_INFO_DWARF5     n
```

Depending on the config file source (eg. whether it's the Ubuntu version), you may need to run:

```
scripts/config --disable DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT
```

Comment: On 6.2.12 (and various versions before) I needed to add `scripts/config --disable DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT` to the list above.

Comment: @MaxGörner thanks! interesting, I'll test it

Comment: In the config I use (which is based on Ubuntu's config), that's already disabled.

I haven't looked at the original Ubuntu's config, so I can't know if it this flag was already disabled, or if one of the commands in the answer disables it, so I've added this command to the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set as follows the following *.config* symbols:

```
 CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=n

 CONFIG_KGDB=n

 CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=n
```

You should also make sure that CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA is not set by commenting it out,

```
 # CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA
```

All of the info to compile the Linux kernel can be found, quite authoritatively, [on the Linux Kernel home page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/CompilingAKernel.html).