# Linux Kernel Compilation: Debug info generated albeit disabling `DEBUG_INFO`

Tags: linux-kernel

I regularly compile Linux kernel on my own. For speed issues, I would like to omit debug information.

A minimal way that reproduces the problem is

```
make localmodconfig
scripts/config --disable DEBUG_INFO
make bindeb-pkg
```

At the end, debug information are still generated, in particular the `linux-image-$VERSION-dbg` debian package. I am puzzled, because I explicitly disabled that. I also checked and they are indeed disabled in the `.config` file right before starting the compilation.

I am aware of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/925079/compile-linux-kernel-deb-pkg-target-without-generating-dbg-package) question, but following its answers does not help.

How could I avoid generating debug information?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that debug information can be automatically activated again. Thus, starting to compile the Kernel with any target (`make`, `make dir-pkg`, `make bindeb-pkg` etc.) is sufficient to change the configuration file `.config` such that debug information are generated, as well as the debug Debian package.

To avoid that various aspects need to be correctly configured. In particular, I had to extend [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1748453/913769) by `scripts/config --disable DEBUG_INFO_DWARF_TOOLCHAIN_DEFAULT` for a Kernel of the 6.2 series.